# Ignore characters in filename in Matlab

Tags: matlab, character

I would like my MATLAB script to run through a folder containing ascii files with bathymetric information. The filenames are structured as follows:

`2013-01-08_ABC_T0.asc`, `2014-02-06_ABC_T0.asc`, `2015-03-07_ABC_T0.asc` etc. for data delivered by a company called `ABC` and;

`2013-07-xx_QQ`, `2015-05-xx_QQ`, etc. for data delivered by a company called `QQ`. The data represent bathymetrical surveys performed in different timesteps. I want to leave the date (`yy/mm/dd`) in the filename for clarity and because I would like to use them later on in the script.

I am new to MATLAB and I don't know how to loop through these files. If I only had the first mentioned set and erased the dates from the file names, I would use:

```
%% loop over bathymetry rasters
disp('Looping over bathymetry rasters...')

for t=0:8
    [x, y, z, ~] = arc_asc_read(['N:\Workspace\rasters\ABC_T' num2str(t)]);
end
```

But how do I ignore the first 11 characters with the more complex filenames?

Comment: Have you looked at [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html)?

Comment: I am not sure how to use this. It will give me a list of the files in the folder, but what I'd like to do is plot a line for each file with ABC in it (and later on, do the same for QQ). I'm looking how to select those files. I just found this link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288917#770034 so I'll try if it works.

Comment: Thank you, dir worked after all. I'll post it as a solution for future dummies like me :)